# HtmlAgilityPack - Parse table and assign rows to custom model

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

So I'm trying to scrape some website data (specifically the first table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%9321_NHL_suspensions_and_fines)). I am using the table xpath, and trying to get the specific row data assigned to my model.

```
public static async Task<List<SuspensionModel>> GetSuspensionData()
{
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

    var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_2020SuspUrl);
    await EnsureSuccessStatusCode(httpResponseMessage);
    var SuspStatsAsHtml = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(SuspStatsAsHtml);

    var suspData = ParseTable(htmlDocument, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr");

    //return ;
}

private static List<SuspensionModel> ParseTable(HtmlDocument htmlDocument, string xPath)
{
    var returnData = new List<SuspensionModel>();
    foreach (HtmlNode row in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath))
    {
        HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("td");
        var arr = new String[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = cells[i].InnerText;
        }

        var susp = new SuspensionModel
        {
            IncidentDate = DateTime.Parse(arr[0]),
            OffenderName = arr[1],
            OffenderTeam = arr[2],
            OffenseDesc = arr[3],
            ActionDate = DateTime.Parse(arr[4]),
            OffenseLength = arr[5],
            SalaryLoss = int.Parse(arr[6])
        };

        returnData.Add(susp);
    }
    return returnData;
}
```

In my `ParseTable` method, where I am assigning values in my model, how can I access the specific cell data in the given row? Basically, I want to do something like:
`foreach row, step through each cell and assign to the correct model value`. As I have it now, my `cells` variable always returns null, so I assume I am not using `HtmlAgilityPack` correctly.

Any assistance is appreciated here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this. I was missing two things, and it turns out it wasn't related to HtmlAgilityPack.

1. I needed to add .Skip(1) to my foreach row so that it skipped the table header row.

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath).Skip(1))
```

2. I needed to fix my SalaryLoss value. I was assigning it as an int, but I needed to change that to a double as it was a currency value.

```
SalaryLoss = double.Parse(arr[6], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
```